# How to make python ignore an object for garbage collection?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

At the start of my code, I load in a huge (33GB) pickled object. This object is essentially a huge graph with many interconnected nodes.

Periodically, I run gc.collect(). When I have the huge object loaded in, this takes 100 seconds. When I change my code to not load in the huge object, gc.collect() takes .5 seconds. I assume that this is caused by python checking through every subobject of this object for reference cycles every time I call gc.collect().

**I know that neither the huge object, nor any of the objects it references when it is loaded in at the start, will ever need to be garbage collected. How do I tell python this, so that I can avoid the 100s gc time?**

Comment: Maybe look into `gc.is_tracked(large_object)`?

Comment: Why are you manually bcalling `gc.collect` to begin with?

Comment: If possible don't use pickle to serialize a 30gb data set. Such large data usually has a more specialized representation. What data do you handle?

Answer (score 5):

In python 3.7 you might be able to hack something using https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.freeze

```
allocate_a_lot()
gc.freeze() # move all objects to a permanent generation. none will be collected
allocate_some_more()
gc.collect() # collect all non-frozen objects
gc.unfreeze() # return to sanity
```

This said, I think that python does not offer the tools for what you want. In general all garbage collected languages do not want you to do manual memory management.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. However, whether or not it would prevent the object from getting garbage collected were there no reference to it, **it is not reducing the gc time down to where it is when the object is not loaded**. Sorry about removing the 'chosen answer', I shouldn't have put it there before trying the solution.

Comment: No problem about removing the accept. Can you do a C level profile of the code? I find it suspect that gc takes 100sec even with huge heaps. Something like the linux perf tools.

Comment: You can also try to set larger limits in gc.set_threshold. Or in the extreme disable the circular garbage collector entirely with gc.disable. The refcounting gc remains alive.

Comment: At the end of the day, my code ends up working fine when I just remove the gc.collect() call. That doesn't resolve the issue I originally brought up, but it means that it is no longer necessary for me to solve that issue.